# Word for a person who is always lying?

Tags: early-modern-english

What is the most suitable word for a person who doesn't feel shame in telling a lie? Or is always lying?

Is 'Proud Liar' a good word?

Comment: Someone who always lies is called a *compulsive liar*.

Comment: @Mick What about Pathological Liar?

Comment: Pathological lying is pretty extreme. For someone who doesn't care if they deceive people but will tell the truth when it suits them, you could just call them a *habitual* liar.

Comment: Which are you asking about? A person who is always lying? Or a person who does not feel shame about lying?

Comment: @Mick *Compulsive* does not mean *always*. So a "compulsive liar" is not someone who "always lies". But what exactly does the OP mean by someone who "always lies"? Does anyone "always" lie? Typically a person who thinks nothing of lying has no interest in "always" lying. Sometimes it suits their purposes to tell the truth. But my guess is that the term that is being sought is *compulsive liar*, meaning that they feel "compelled" to lie, if they think it gives them an advantage. But that is not always..

Comment: Mendacious liar

Answer (score 2):

> [**Pathological lying**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathological_lying) (also called **pseudologia fantastica** and **mythomania**) is a behavior of habitual or compulsive lying. It was first described in the medical literature in 1891 by Anton Delbrueck. Although it is a controversial topic, pathological lying has been defined as "falsification entirely disproportionate to any discernible end in view, may be extensive and very complicated, and may manifest over a period of years or even a lifetime". ***The individual may be aware they are lying, or may believe they are telling the truth.*** Sometimes however, the individual may be lying to make their life seem more exciting when in reality they believe their life is unpleasant or boring.

---

> It has been shown through lie detector tests that PF (pseudologia fantastica) **patients exhibit arousal, stress, and guilt from their deception**. This is different from psychopaths, who experience none of those reactions. People affected by antisocial disorder lie for external personal profit in the forms of money, sex, and power. PF is strictly internal. The difference between borderline personality disorder and PF is that BPD patients desperately try to cope with their feeling of abandonment, mistreatment, or rejection by making empty threats of suicide or false accusations of abandonment. **Pathological liars do not feel rejected, they have high levels of self-assurance that help them lie successfully.**

Comment: Also habitual or chronic liar: https://www.truthaboutdeception.com/lying-and-deception/confronting-a-partner/compulsive-lying/types-of-liars.html

Comment: Pathological lying generally takes place because of an underlying shame or anxiety. Can it be applied to someone who lies proudly?

Comment: Make of the edit what you will. # not a doctor ;)

Answer (score 1):

Someone who feels no shame when lying is called a *shameless* liar. A lie that is so obvious that it hardly needs pointing out is called a *blatant* lie. Someone who tells *blatant* lies is called a *barefaced* liar

[Cambridge Dictionary: blatant](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/blatant)

[Cambridge Dictionary: barefaced](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/barefaced)

Answer (score 0):

**sociopathic liar**

*What is the Difference Between a Sociopath, a Compulsive, a Pathological, a Chronic, and a Habitual Liar?* –[truthaboutdeception.com](https://www.truthaboutdeception.com/lying-and-deception/confronting-a-partner/compulsive-lying/types-of-liars.html)

> **A sociopath is typically defined as someone who lies incessantly to get their way and does so with little concern for others.** A sociopath is often goal-oriented (i.e., lying is focused—it is done to get one's way). Sociopaths have little regard or respect for the rights and feelings of others.

---

*sociopath* /ˈsōsēōˌpaTH/ noun

> a person with a personality disorder manifesting itself in extreme antisocial attitudes and behavior and a lack of conscience. –[Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=sociopath&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

Answer (score 0):

**Inveterate Liar**

Oxford Learner's Dictionary (online) informs us:

**Inveterate:** (adj.)

```
     1. (of a person) always doing something...and unlikely to stop.
```

- *An inveterate liar*  [actual word/phrase given as an example by Oxford Learner's dictionary]

Thus we might say: Even when he was telling the truth members of his family did not believe him because they knew him to be an *inveterate liar.*